# How to indent a complete paragraph with Prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

Is it possible to indent a complete paragraph of text with Prawn?

So not just the first line of a paragraph like `:indent_paragraphs => some_number` does? But all the text in that paragraph.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
Prawn::Document.generate('indented.pdf') do |pdf|
  pdf.indent(20) do
    pdf.text "indented paragraph"
  end
end
```